# How to get only email value from HTML files using DOM ? Only Email value not like link

Tags: php, html, email, dom

http://www.frosher.com/schools/acme-academy-burdwan/contact

This is the page link which i saved in my folder and get the their address with their all contact information of the school. You also seen their is email and web link before the Google map block. I want to get email value.

Just save this html page in scraping folder. Here's my code:

```
<?php 
include('simple_html_dom.php');//Required
$i = 0; 
$dir = 'scraping/';//folder name in which your html file
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
        if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
            $i++;
    }
}
$filenames = array();
foreach(glob('scraping/*.*') as $filename){
    $filenames[] = $filename;//get all files name which are in my folder
}
$i = 1;
foreach($filenames as $val){
    $doc = new DomDocument();
    $doc  = file_get_html($val);
    $ret = $doc->find('div[class=span5]'); 
    foreach($doc->find('.span7') as $element){
        $contact = $element->plaintext;     
        if (preg_match("/\bEmail\b/i", $contact, $match)) {
            $n = 0; // i have used $n for counting because in span7 div their are two a tag so i need only first time value.
            foreach($doc->find('.span7 a') as $element){
                if($n == 0){                    
                    $email = $element; 
                    $n = $n+1;
                }                   
            }           
        }
        else{
            $email = 'Null';
        }           
        echo $email;
        
    }       
    echo '<br/>';
}
?>
```

This is php script code save it with a file name and place both the php file and scraping folder in common folder like leo is the folder in which php file placed and scraping folder also in it.

Now run the php file and you will see the output. If not then you have to include also "simple_html_dom.php" in leo folder.

Comment: Show some code so we can see what you've tried?

Comment: Incomplete question. Please brief us with code or description.

Comment: *"I have written php script to get email value"* --- Sweet, now can "WE" see it too?

Comment: @Leo Edit your question with the code in "it", not in a comment.

Comment: I have Edit the question !! Please Check. @Fred .Is it sufficient for you guys.

Comment: help you harvest email addresses to spam, nope. p.s phpmyadmin is not a databse

Comment: leave the phpmyadmin , Can you get only email value text not email value like a link from html files ? @Dagon

Comment: yes i can; thanks for asking

Comment: Thanks for taking initiative @Dagon

Comment: Updated my question with code and some more information !! Please check! @Dagon

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting whole  tag then try following

```
foreach($doc->find('.span7 a') as $element){    

    $email = $element; 
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    //now you can check email
}
```

Comment: It Show "[email protected] /* */". Can i send some more code if you guys doesn't understand. Or may be you guys give me another option to get email value.@parixit

Comment: Updated my question Please Check @parixit